# Why does PHP `shell_exec` not show correct `ps` output?

Tags: php, apache

I try to get all users processes with PHP `shell_exec` function:

`shell_exec("ps aux")`

For any reason, this command prints `apache` and `root` processes, however, it doesn't print any other users processes. Even when I run following:

`shell_exec("ps -u myuser1 2>&1")`

PHP is unable to print any processes.

Does anyone knows the reason of such `shell_exec` behavior and has idea how to fix it?

Comment: It is probably related to the permissions of the `apache` user rather than anything in PHP itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try make echo of result

echo shell_exec("ps aux");